# How can you override a spring property in application.yml for a Spring Boot application using the docker run command?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, environment-variables, application.properties

I have a dockerized spring boot application with an application.yml containing the following property:

```yaml
rest-template:
    connection-timeout: 1000
    read-timeout: 1000
```

Now let's say I want to update the connection timeout value when running the docker run command. I am aware that one of ways is to update the application.yml file:

```yaml
rest-template:
    connection-timeout: ${REST_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT:1000}
    read-timeout: ${REST_READ_TIMEOUT:1000}
```

Then we can run the docker run command as follows:

```sh
docker container run -d --name test-service -e REST_CONNECTION_TIMOUT=5000 test-service-img
```

But say if I wanted to update this without having to use REST_CONNECTION_TIMOUT in the application.yml.

How would this property this map to the env variable in the docker command ?

Comment: You can write a custom run command on the command line which will update your file with e.g. sed if available prior to launching your Spring Boot application. Meanwhile, the clean way would be what you already described in your question with env vars, or at the very least, to overide that file building a custom image.

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on the [relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding-from-environment-variables) of Spring Boot - one of its features is to map environment variables to configuration properties.

In your case, you can use:

```
... -e RESTTEMPLATE_CONNECTIONTIMEOUT=5000 -e RESTTEMPLATE_READTIMEOUT=5000 ...
```